# why is the EditText input box doesn't show up?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have the latest version of android studio, in it i have written code to have two headlines and an a input field, `EditText` and its `TextView` label. the code as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headline1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/heading"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headline_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headline2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headline1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/register_here"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headline_size" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first_name"
        android:id="@+id/tvFirstName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headline2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvFirstName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvFirstName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFirstName"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But in the design view or when i ran it, it did not show up the `EditText` input field. Even funnier, when i put the device to landscape mode the `EditText` showed at the top above all headings. [Here is the video](https://youtu.be/CNdDBip_UfA) to see whats going on. Why this happens? how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not setting proper position of your `EditText`.
replace your `EditText` with this.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvFirstName" 
       />
```

`android:layout_below="@+id/tvFirstName"` this will align your `EditText` below your `tvFirstName TextView`

**Edit:**

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headline2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvFirstName"
       />
```

Comment: the EditText should display to the right of tvFirstName and the width should expand to the right side of teh screen

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it's working fine on my emulator. The Edittext is not showing because it is there but somewhere scattered that's why it shows up when you change the orientation. Try this code maybe it will help:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headline1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/heading"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headline2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headline1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/register_here"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headline_size" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first_name"
        android:id="@+id/tvFirstName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headline2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
        android:hint="FirstName"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvFirstName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvFirstName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFirstName"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: it works :) but one tiny problem. teh EditText align to the top of TextView so the text i enter to it a bit below "First Name". the horizontal center line of First Name and EditText must be in teh same line